Fixed value for a prior year line chart in Power BI
I have a line and column chart in PowerBI. Columns shows my total sales for each month; i also have a slicer to filter by year. I have a measure to show the average of the full year (fixed, i recieved help on my previously question)
fix a value for a line chart in Power BI
But now i want to do the same but for the prior year.
This is my fixed measure for the current year:
FixedCurrent= DIVIDE (
    CALCULATE ( DIVIDE([Sales],50), ALL ( 'Data' ) ),
    CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Calendar'[Month] ), ALL ( 'Calendar' ) )
)

and i already tried something like this but it didnt work:
Planchado Prior Año Anterior = 
    DIVIDE (
        CALCULATE (
            DIVIDE([Sales], 50),
            ALL ( 'Data' ),
            SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR ( 'Calendar'[Date] )
        ),
        CALCULATE (
            DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Calendar'[month] ),
            ALL ( 'Calendar' ),
            SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR ( 'Calendar'[Date] )
        )
    )

this is an example of what im expecting to have keeping the slicer too:


so you want to display the last year's average in the chart? What do you mean by keeping the slicer? Could you pls also provide some sample data and expected output You can draw the chart in excel and paste the screenshot here to have a better understanding.

Try to use PARALLELPERIOD('Calendar'[Date], -1, YEAR) to shift the data context to the prior year so you can calculate the previous year fixed value :
FixedPriorYear = 
DIVIDE (
    CALCULATE ( 
        DIVIDE([Sales], 50), 
        ALL ( 'Data' ),
        PARALLELPERIOD('Calendar'[Date], -1, YEAR)
    ),
    CALCULATE ( 
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Calendar'[Month] ), 
        ALL ( 'Calendar' ),
        PARALLELPERIOD('Calendar'[Date], -1, YEAR)
    )
)

